# Elasticsearch serilog error with no details

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, serilog

I have the following code which logs into an elasticsearch hosted in docker:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticUri))
                {
                    IndexFormat = "main-service-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication(elasticUsername, elasticPassword),
                    MinimumLogEventLevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose,
                })
                .WriteTo.File("Logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
                .CreateLogger();

            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(message => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

and I get the following error as soon as I start my app:

```
2020-02-20T13:39:47.8467752Z Caught exception while preforming bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: An error occurred while sending the request.. Call: Status code unknown from: POST /_bulk
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.HandleElasticsearchClientException(RequestData data, Exception clientException, IElasticsearchResponse response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.FinalizeResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, IRequestPipeline pipeline, List`1 seenExceptions, TResponse response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.DoRequest[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.Bulk[TResponse](PostData body, BulkRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatchChecked[T](IEnumerable`1 events)
   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatch(IEnumerable`1 events)
2020-02-20T13:39:50.0903909Z Caught exception while preforming bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: An error occurred while sending the request.. Call: Status code unknown from: POST /_bulk
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.HandleElasticsearchClientException(RequestData data, Exception clientException, IElasticsearchResponse response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.FinalizeResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, IRequestPipeline pipeline, List`1 seenExceptions, TResponse response)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.DoRequest[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.Bulk[TResponse](PostData body, BulkRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatchChecked[T](IEnumerable`1 events)
   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatch(IEnumerable`1 events)
```

How can I get more information on the error? I'm using following versions

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch" Version="8.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Comment: Can you post elasticUri?

Comment: Found the issue. Had http instead of https in url.